# Pulling Data Loop using R

Tags: r, date, loops, stocks

Hello I am trying to write a loop that will help me retrieve data from a site using a loop, but I am stuck on how to paste the `date` onto the `URL`. For example, I am trying to retrieve the last 5 days of data....

```
# Get Todays Date
Friday <- Sys.Date()

# Get Previous 5 days
Thursday <- Friday - 1
Wednesday <- Thursday -1
Tuesday <- Wednesday -1
Monday <- Tuesday -1

#Make Them "readable" for Site`
Friday <- format(Friday, "%Y%m%d")
Thursday<- format(Thursday, "%Y%m%d")
Wednesday<- format(Wednesday, "%Y%m%d")
Tuesday<- format(Tuesday, "%Y%m%d")
Monday<-format(Monday, "%Y%m%d")

#I would like to set what stock I want to retrieve prior to looping
#What Stock and exchange?
GOOG.O

#Get Data by Date
FRIDAY <- read.delim(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE,"http://hopey.netfonds.no/tradedump.php?date=20140214&paper=GOOG.O&csv_format=txt")
```

Comment: The backticks are useful for inline code but for code chunks just indent everything four spaces.  Alternatively highlight the code and click the code block button (which looks like {} )

Comment: @dason Thanks man! kind of new to this still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you try to do here, just use `paste` or `paste0`:

```
stock.name <- "GOOG.O"

FRIDAY <- read.delim(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactor=FALSE,
            paste0("http://hopey.netfonds.no/tradedump.php?date=", Friday,
                   "&paper=", stock.name,
                   "&csv_format=txt")
          )
```

Comment: `paste0` is a short form for `paste(...,sep="")`.